# cannot import name NonlinearConstraint

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to run the optimization example with non-linear constraints shown here

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

```
>>> def cons_f(x):
...     return [x[0]**2 + x[1], x[0]**2 - x[1]]
>>> def cons_J(x):
...     return [[2*x[0], 1], [2*x[0], -1]]
>>> def cons_H(x, v):
...     return v[0]*np.array([[2, 0], [0, 0]]) + v[1]*np.array([[2, 0], [0, 0]])
>>> from scipy.optimize import NonlinearConstraint
>>> nonlinear_constraint = NonlinearConstraint(cons_f, -np.inf, 1, jac=cons_J, hess=cons_H)
```

But when I try to import `NonlinearConstraint` this is what I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name NonlinearConstraint
```

I'm running scipy v.1.0.0

```
>>> import scipy
>>> print scipy.__version__
1.0.0
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need `scipy >= 1.1` or a master-branch based install!

As 1.1 was released recently (05.05.18), there are chances for binary-builds (depends a bit on how you use scipy).

Compare [1.1's optimize/**init**.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.1.0/scipy/optimize/__init__.py):

```
...
from ._lsq import least_squares, lsq_linear
from ._constraints import (NonlinearConstraint,
                           LinearConstraint,
                           Bounds)
from ._hessian_update_strategy import HessianUpdateStrategy, BFGS, SR1

__all__ = [s for s in dir() if not s.startswith('_')]
...
```

with [1.0.1's optimize/**init**.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.0.1/scipy/optimize/__init__.py):

```
...
from ._lsq import least_squares, lsq_linear

__all__ = [s for s in dir() if not s.startswith('_')]
...
```

More indications are available in the [1.1 release-text](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases/tag/v1.1.0):

> scipy.optimize improvements
>
> The method trust-constr has been added to scipy.optimize.minimize. The
>   method switches between two implementations depending on the problem
>   definition. For equality constrained problems it is an implementation of
>   a trust-region sequential quadratic programming solver and, when
>   inequality constraints are imposed, it switches to a trust-region
>   interior point method. Both methods are appropriate for large scale
>   problems. Quasi-Newton options BFGS and SR1 were implemented and can be
>   used to approximate second order derivatives for this new method. Also,
>   finite-differences can be used to approximate either first-order or
>   second-order derivatives.

which is actually the solver introducing those abstractions.

Additionally, `optimize/_constraints.py` does not exist in [1.01](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/v1.0.1/scipy/optimize).

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks